# Symbolic software packages for Matrix expressions?

Tags: matrix, symbolic-computation

We know that $\mathbf A$ is symmetric and positive-definite. We know that $\mathbf B$ is orthogonal:

Question: is $\mathbf B \cdot\mathbf A \cdot\mathbf B^\top$ symmetric and positive-definite? 
Answer: Yes.

Question: Could a computer have told us this?
Answer: Probably.

Are there any symbolic algebra systems (like Mathematica) that handle and propagate known facts about matrices?

Edit: To be clear I'm asking this question about abstractly defined matrices. I.e. I don't have explicit entries for $A$ and $B$, I just know that they are both matrices and have particular attribues like symetric, positive definite, etc....

Comment: What I'm missing is software that treats matrices symbolically (i.e., not as arrays). I'd want to be able to talk about some symmetric matrix $\mathbf C$ without having to fret about its entries.

Comment: There are a few projects working on this. I happen to be familiar with the implementation in SymPy. It's buggy but slowly being built up.

Comment: This sounds like automated theorem proving. The trick then is to include a sufficient set of axioms in your engine so that it can then be deduced efficiently by automated reasoning (think PROLOG). If I was to design such a thing, the property you cite above is definitely something I'd encode as a fact/known relation rather than trying.

On the other hand, there is Prof Paolo Bientinesi at RWTH Aachen University. In his dissertation he talks about automatic derivation of linear algebra algorithms. He uses Mathematica in a symbolic way. http://www.aices.rwth-aachen.de:8080/~pauldj/

Comment: I know Paolo's stuff and the FLAME library. I don't think it can do this.

Comment: I agree that computer algebra systems for matrices would be great, but seem to be missing. I have put a bounty to increase the chance of getting an answer.

Comment: @Memming I am not familiar enough with the topic to be able to tell if this could be useful or not, but please see http://www.xact.es/

Comment: @Szabolcs as far as I can tell from the example, it works with a fixed size tensor. So, no. We are looking for something that would work for variable size (N by M) matrices.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

### Edit: This is now in SymPy

```
$ isympy
In [1]: A = MatrixSymbol('A', n, n)
In [2]: B = MatrixSymbol('B', n, n)
In [3]: context = Q.symmetric(A) & Q.positive_definite(A) & Q.orthogonal(B)
In [4]: ask(Q.symmetric(B*A*B.T) & Q.positive_definite(B*A*B.T), context)
Out[4]: True
```

### Older answer that shows other work

So after looking into this for a while this is what I've found.

The current answer to my specific question is "No, there is no current system that can answer this question." There are however a few things that seem to come close.

First, Matt Knepley and Lagerbaer both pointed to [work by Diego Fabregat and Paolo Bientinesi](http://www.aices.rwth-aachen.de:8080/aices/preprint/documents/AICES-2012-01-02.pdf). This work shows both the potential importance and the feasibility of this problem. It's a good read. Unfortunately I'm not certain exactly how his system works or what it is capable of (if anyone knows of other public material on this topic do let me know).

Second, there is a tensor algebra library written for Mathematica called [xAct](http://xact.es/) which handles symmetries and such symbolically. It does some things very well but is not tailored to the special case of linear algebra.

Third, these rules are written down formally in a couple of libraries for [Coq](http://coq.inria.fr/), an automated theorem proving assistant (Google search for coq linear/matrix algebra to find a few). This is a powerful system which unfortunately seems to require human interaction.

After [talking with some theorem prover people](https://sympa-roc.inria.fr/wws/arc/coq-club/2012-02/msg00141.html) they suggest looking into logic programming (i.e. Prolog, which Lagerbaer also suggested) for this sort of thing. To my knowledge this hasn't yet been done - I may play with it in the future.

Update: I've implemented this using the [Maude system](http://maude.cs.uiuc.edu). My code is hosted [on github](http://github.com/mrocklin/matrix-algebra)

Comment: When I found that there was no good system, my first instinct was to write a prolog program. :)

Comment: I added a link at the bottom to a side project of mine that deals with this problem.

Comment: Could `SymPy` infer simplification of matrix multiplication and inversion?

Answer (score 4):

Some symbolic matrix computations (e.g., block matrix completion) can be done with the package NCAlgebra http://www.math.ucsd.edu/~ncalg/ (which runs under mathematica).

Bergman http://servus.math.su.se/bergman/ is a package in Lisp with similar capabilities.

Some relevant papers:
http://math.ucsd.edu/~helton/osiris/COMPALG2000/ohRevisIJC.pdf
http://math.ucsd.edu/~thesis/thesis/dkronewitter/dkronewitter.pdf
http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/00207170600882346

Answer (score 4):

I think most `CAS` systems can show this for `2x2` and `3x3` matrices given a symbolic orthonormal $\mathbf B$ construct, such as rotation matrices. In the end, you will have to decompose the result to figure out if it is positive definite or not. Symmetry is easier to show.

The question then becomes, what about a `N` dimensional matrix? Maybe you can come up with an inductive scheme where for `N-1 x N-1` is assumed to be true and then construct a new block matrix with overall size `N x N` to prove that is positive definite and symmetric.

So the final question, of which software is better suited for the task (if any), my experience has been with `MATLAB/MuPad` and `Derive` (still use it) and neither of them handle vectors and matrices very well. `MATLAB` breaks everything down into components, and `Derive` can declare *`Non-scalars`* but it does not apply any simplification rules to them.

I hope this posting is going to provide some more insight into this kind of "hole" and how to fill it. For me, I want some software that can help me simplify expressions with multiple dot and cross products of vectors, together with rotation matrices use well known identities such as: $\vec a \times (\vec b \times \vec c) = (\vec a \cdot \vec b)\vec c - (\vec a \cdot \vec c) \vec b$

Answer (score 3):

Maple 15 cannot do it. It has no property "Orthogonal" for matrices (although it has Symmetric and PositiveDefinite).

Comment: Updated to Maple 16 -> no property "Orthogonal" neither.

Answer (score 2):

In Mathematica you can at least check these properties for specific matrices.  For example, the matrix `A` as you described:

```
In[1]:= A = {{2.0,-1.0,0.0},{-1.0,2.0,-1.0},{0.0,-1.0,2.0}};
        {SymmetricMatrixQ[A],PositiveDefiniteMatrixQ[A]}
Out[2]= {True,True}
```

For matrix `B`:

```
In[3]:= B = {{0, -0.80, -0.60}, {0.80, -0.36, 0.48}, {0.60, 0.48, -0.64}};
        Transpose[B] == Inverse[B]
Out[4]= True
```

Then:

```
In[5]:= c = B.A.Transpose[B];
        {SymmetricMatrixQ[c],PositiveDefiniteMatrixQ[c]}
Out[6]= {True,True}
```

[Mathematica Matrices and Linear Algebra Documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/MatricesAndLinearAlgebra.html)

Comment: It is my understand that the predicates above are verifying that property for a given matrix, rather than symbolically propagating these properties as Matt asks for above.

Comment: Ah yes. Sorry about that. I misunderstood.

Answer (score 2):

It's been a while since I last used either of these packages, but I thought that you could do this in languages such as Mathematica through the use of assertions. Something like Assert[A, Symmetric] tells Mathematica that A is a symmetric matrix, and so on. I don't have access to either handy at the moment, so this is something that would have to be checked.

Comment: I think you mean the Mathematica command [`Assuming`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Assuming.html) instead of `Assert`. `Assuming` will apply these assumptions when simplifying or integrating an expression, but the documentation is not clear about whether matrix properties are propagated. My guess is that such properties are not carried through symbolic computations.

Comment: That could be true. Like I said, this was eons ago (back in my graduate school days). But I do remember being able to do something like this once. (Perhaps it was with MuPad, as implemented in Scientific WorkPlace.) But I no longer have access to SWP to check that (Windows-only, and I don't have an emulator on my box).

Comment: MuPAD is part of Matlab now. According to the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/mupad/math/math-assumptions-when-use.html), the usage of assumptions is similar to that of Mathematica.

Comment: MuPAD can only deal with fixed size matrix, and doesn't take arbitrary assumptions such as positive definiteness. Also it cannot answer the question of positive definiteness of B A B' originally asked.

Comment: @Memming: Fair enough. As I said, my memory of MuPAD was substantially out of date, as I last used the program regularly around 2006 (when I switched from PC's to Macs).